# How to play youtube song in terminal with ffplay and youtube-dl

Tags: linux, shell, audio, youtube-dl, ffplay

Is there any you to stream any music the terminal with youtube-dl and ffplay
I know that ffplay can play audio with shell
`$ audio stram | ffplay -i -`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
youtube-dl -f bestaudio  ytsearch:"SONG NAME" -o - 2>/dev/null | ffplay -nodisp -autoexit -i - &>/dev/null
```

Or:

```
youtube-dl -f bestaudio VIDEO_URL -o - 2>/dev/null | ffplay -nodisp -autoexit -i - &>/dev/null
```

Comment: Can you please explain this command? I know the basic usage of youtube-dl.

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/what_is_dev_null/ This was interesting I didn't know it. Thanks

Comment: In this case youtube-dl not writing the downloaded data to a file instead it's piping it to ffplay to play directly.

Answer (score 0):

..and if you mordernize the command a little you can play YT-videos from the terminal without ads.

youtube-dl -f mp4 YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL -o - 2>/dev/null | ffplay -autoexit -i - &>/dev/null

Due to YouTube at the moment are throttlening youtube-dl I'm now using yt-dlp instead. Same codebase but no throttlening :)

yt-dlp -f mp4 YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL -o - 2>/dev/null | ffplay -autoexit -i - &>/dev/null